# How to return a class object from a basic function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

So I'm currently writing a program where I need a function that I run recursively to return a class object. See code below:

```
def checkEqual (p1:Player, p2:Player, playerListNum):
    if p1 == p2 and playerListNum >= 2:
        np2 = r.choice(verySpecificListVariable)
        print(type(np2))
        checkEqual(p1, np2, playerListNum)
    else:
        print(type(p2))
        return p2
```

Then later in the code I run:

```
p1 = r.choice(verySpecificListVariable)
p2 = checkEqual(p1, r.choice(verySpecificListVariable), len(verySpecificListVariable))
print(type(p2))
```

verySpecificListariable being a list of class objects.

So the first two prints give me what i'm looking for: a class object. However the last one throws a NoneType. From this I deduced that for some odd reason, the function was turning the class object into a NoneType as soon as it returns it into the p2 variable.

(at `p2 = checkEqual(p1, r.choice(verySpecificListVariable), len(verySpecificListVariable))`)

I need to reference p2 later in the code as a class object, but obviously the NoneType does NOT like that. Thank you for your time, and any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have `return p2` in the `else` block. What do you return in the `if` block?

Comment: @Barmar if I were to do that, the function would not work recursively as intended.

Comment: If you were to do what? Why wouldn't it work recursively if you changed `checkEqual(p1, np2, playerListNum)` to `return checkEqual(p1, np2, playerListNum)`?

Comment: What is the `playerListNum` parameter for?